# An example of a closed bounded subset of a Hilbert space that is not totally bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $l^2$ be the set of complex square summable series. Can you give an example of a subset of $l^2$ which is bounded and closed but not totally bounded. I’m new to this concept so I’m not that good at coming up with examples.

Comment: Consider the canonical orthonormal basis.

Comment: To expand on Math1000 comment, you can pick $\epsilon$ small enough so that only one of element of the orthonormal basis is in each neighborhood. Then it will take infinitely many neighborhoods and we see that the set is not totally bounded. Yet at the same time, the whole set exists in the unit ball so it is bounded.

Comment: If I’m correct the orthonormal basis has 1 at one coordinate and the rest of them are zero. But how does this show that this set is closed? Can you please explain it more clearly.

Comment: Also epsilon less than root 2 will work if I’m correct.

Comment: @JohnMitchell It's closed in the same way the integers are closed in $\mathbb R.$

Comment: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $Y$ is a subset of $X$  and $r>0$  such that $d(y,y')\geq r$ for all unequal $y,y'\in Y$ then $Y$ is closed in $X.$ PROOF: For $x\in X\setminus Y:$  (i). If $B_d(x,r/2)\cap Y$ is empty then $ x\not \in \overline Y$. (ii). If $B_d(x,r/2)\cap Y$ is not empty then it contains exactly one $y\in Y,$ and then $B_d(x, d(x,y))\cap Y$ is empty so again $x\not \in \overline Y.$

Answer (score 0):

The closed unit ball $B=\{x:\|x\|\le 1\}$ is one such example. That its complement is open can be shown using the triangle inequality (this part is not specific to Hilbert space; this kind of reasoning works in any metric space.) The lack of total boundedness follows from the fact that $B$ contains all standard basis vectors
$$(1, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \ (0, 1, 0, 0, \dots), \dots$$
The distance between any two of such vectors is $\sqrt{2}$. If $B$ is covered by finitely many set, some of these sets   must contain more than one of the basis vectors, and therefore have diameter at least $\sqrt{2}$.